# Programa em C que executa comandos no cmd

Tags: c, cmd

Estou querendo criar um executável em C que abra o prompt e execute comandos através dele, o executável é uma solução para o problema "ethernet não tem uma configuração de ip válida".
até consegui compilar um, mas alguns comandos pede elevação...alguém pode me ajudar com isso? Ou se tiver uma forma mais simples para isso ajudaria muito também.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

    system("ipconfig /release");
    system("ipconfig /renew");
    system("ipconfig /flushdns");
    system("ipconfig /registerdns");
    system("nbtstat -RR");
    system("netsh int ip reset all");
    system("netsh winsock reset");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Para **executar** seus **comandos 1 por vez**, apenas **adicione o comando:**  **<kbd>`cmd /c`</kbd>** .

É este o **interpretador** de **comando**, e é ele que vai **“usar/interpretar
”** os seus **comandos**

**<kbd>`O layout do seu código ficaria dessa forma :`</kbd>**

---

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    system("cmd /c ipconfig /release");
    system("cmd /c ipconfig /renew");
    system("cmd /c ipconfig /flushdns");
    system("cmd /c ipconfig /registerdns");
    system("cmd /c nbtstat -RR");
    system("cmd /c netsh int ip reset all");
    system("cmd /c netsh winsock reset");
}
```

---

**<kbd>`Ou de uma forma concatenada em uma só linha, o interpretador vai “entender” que é parar chamar/executar comando por comando, um após o outro obedecendo o operador "&"!`</kbd>**

**<kbd>`Onde o código ficaria com esse layout "cmd /c Comando & comando & comando &..." :`</kbd>**

---

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    system("cmd /c ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew & ipconfig /flushdns & ipconfig /registerdns & nbtstat -RR & netsh int ip reset all & netsh winsock reset");
}
```

<kbd>**`• Observações sobre os operadores: &, |, && e ||`**</kbd>

Conforme o **cenário/comportamento** dos seus **comandos**, você pode fazer **uso quando:**

> <kbd>**`execute & execute & execute`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior & execute`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`executou_sem_erro && então_execute_também`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`executou_com_erro || execute_também_porque_deu_erro`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro`**</kbd>
>
> <kbd>**`executou_sem_erro && então_execute || execute_esse_no_primeiro_deu_erro`**</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Olá, você precisa utilizar o shellExecute para fazer isso, ele ira executar um .bat com esses comandos.

Exemplo: seria algo como isso.

```
ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", "c:\\net.bat", NULL, "c:\\windows\\system", SW_SHOWNORMAL );
```

ou

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/c ipconfig /release /c ipconfig /renew /c ipconfig /flushdns /c ipconfig /registerdns /c nbtstat -RR /cnetsh int ip reset all /cwinsock reset ", 0, SW_HIDE); //para ver a tela do CMD substitua para SW_HIDE por SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

[Documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Desculpa, não compreendi como aplicar esse comando no código

Comment: Faça um teste com o segundo comando, nele você não tem o HWND basta copiar e colar, se funcionar de uma olhada na documentação para intender como ele funciona.

Comment: Usei o segundo comando, compilou porém ele dá "Process returned 0" pelo que vi na documentação esse retorno é um erro. Além disso, aparentemente os comandos do cmd não são executados corretamente, ja revisei todos mas continua falhando. O erro que dá é "linha de comando não reconhecida ou incompleta."

Comment: tenta substituir o quarto parâmetro por esse `/c ipconfig /release  ipconfig /renew  ipconfig /flushdns  ipconfig /registerdns nbtstat -RR netsh int ip reset all winsock reset `

Comment: Obrigado! ainda está falhando mas desse jeito consegui encontrar a sintaxe que o cmd entende, troquei o "/c" por "/k" para visualizar o que estava acontecendo e vi que para o  "ipconfig" quando tem mais de um comando deve ser escrito assim: "/k ipconfig [/release | /renew | /flushdns | /registerdns]". Dessa forma compilou, só deu erro no "renew", diz '/renew' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.